# How to render filitered countries when clicking the show button using Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs. I am trying to implement a search filter for countries from this [Json server](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all) using `axios.get()`. 
If the filter array contains only 1 country then [my application works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE5xF.png) otherwise if the filter array contains more than 1 but less than 10 countries [I want to output this result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Leiaj.png) I am able to successfully achieve the filter part  on my browser but when I click on "show" button it only outputs on the console.

Here's my code :

```
const ShowBetween1to10 = ({country, buttonHandler}) => {
  return(
    <div key={country.alpha2Code}>
      <p>
        {country.name}
        <button onClick = {buttonHandler}>show</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  )

}

const App = () => {
  const [countries,setCountries] = useState([])
  const [filter,setFilter] = useState('')
  //const [flag, setFlag] = useState('')

  useEffect(() =>{
    axios.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
    .then(response => setCountries(response.data))
  }, [])

  //console.log('countries[] = ',countries)

  const buttonHandlerOf = (alpha2Code) => {
    const url = `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${alpha2Code}`

    return (axios.get(url).then(response =>{
      console.log(response.data)
      console.log(response.data.languages)
      return(
        <div>
          {view(response.data)}
        </div>
      )})
    )
  }

  const view = (country) =>{
    //console.log(country.languages)
    const lang = country.languages.map(lang => lang.name)
    console.log(lang)
    return(
      <div>
            <h1>{country.name}</h1>
            <h2>languages</h2>
            <ul>{printLanguages(lang)}</ul>
            <img src={country.flag}  alt="flag photo" height="100" width="100"/>
      </div>
    ) 
  }
  const rows = () => {
    const len = countriesToShow.length 
    if(len > 10){
      return(<p>Too many matches, specify another filter</p>)
    }
    else if(len >=1 && len <= 10){
      if(len === 1){
        const country = countriesToShow[0];
        return(
          <div>
            {view(country)}
          </div>
        )
      }
      else{
        return(countriesToShow.map(country => 
          <ShowBetween1to10 
           key ={country.alpha2Code}
           country = {country}
           buttonHandler = {() => buttonHandlerOf(country.alpha2Code)}
          />  
        ))
      }

    }


  }
  const handleFilterChange = (event) => {
    setFilter(event.target.value)
  }
  const countriesToShow = filter === '' ? [] : countries.filter(country =>  {
    return country.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())
  })
  return(
    <div>
      find countries
      <input value={filter} onChange={handleFilterChange} />
      {rows()}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;`
```

If anybody can help me I'll be grateful of you. Start looking from the `else if(len >1 && len <10)` part of `rows()` function and please explain why `view()` is not rendering on the browser but only on the console ?
Thanks a heap !!!

Comment: It Works when your Filter has only one country?

Comment: Your problem is that you are returning HTML from your button handler async method, which has no effect. You need to store your response in some kind of state (e.g. showCountries array), and then display data from that array.

Comment: @zhuber I am now using a state [show,setShow] and I am able to set the state of "show" but I am having trouble of where to add the code to render it? and how to reset "show " state to an empty array after displaying it ??

Answer (score 0):

Your `buttonHandlerOf` is incorrect. You can't render a view from it. Generally you'd need to set the response data to state, which would be then rendered.

Also I'd recommend you to make those view functions that return JSX into separate React components.

```
 const buttonHandlerOf = alpha2Code => {
    const url = `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${alpha2Code}`;

    return axios.get(url).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      console.log(response.data.languages);
      setCountries([response.data]) // set the country to the state here
    });
  };
```

As pointed in the comments, this would remove all other countries, so you could fetch them again when the filter is cleared:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (!filter) {
      axios
        .get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
        .then(response => setCountries(response.data));
    }
  }, [filter]);
```

Alternatively you could add a reset button.

Comment: I don't think that will fix the problem, since all other filtered countries would disappear once you click show on one.

Comment: @zhuber, one option would be to refetch them when the filter is cleared.

Comment: Or just store "shown" one in another state variable.

Comment: @Clarity Thanks a ton ! but  I am unable to understand how would I use  ```<Views />``` component in  ```else if(len > 1 && len <=10  )``` condition of  ```rows()```  function ?

Comment: @AbhishekDasgupta in order to use it like that, `rows` function will have to be transformed into component as well, and then you can compose the components.